# Panels overriding themselves in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

My problem is pretty hard to explain. First of all, I have :

- A JPanel (leftPanel)
- A JScrollPane (lBar), which is created to scroll the leftPanel (--> new JScrollPane(leftPanel))
- A button that adds a new panel in the leftPanel on each click

Here's the result :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFXwh_vofQI

There are two problems :

- With 4 or 5 clicks, the panels are overriding themselves (strange)
  (secondary)
- I would like the button + panels to look nicer (instead
  of a BIG CENTERED button)

The code I use :

```
ActionsPanel panel = new ActionsPanel();
JScrollPane lBar = new JScrollPane(leftPanel);
lBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

The ActionsPanel class :

```
public class ActionsPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JButton newAction;

    public ActionsPanel(final Editor editor)
    {
        this.newAction = new JButton("New");
        this.newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                getActions().add(new Action());
                refresh();
            }
        });

        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        removeAll();
        add(newAction);

        for (Action action : getActions())
        {
            ActionPanel panel = new ActionPanel(action);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            add(panel);
        }

        revalidate();
    }
}
```

The ActionPanel class :

```
public class ActionPanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        setSize(getWidth(), 100);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics.drawString("Ordinal : " + getOrdinal(), 5, 15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice video. Who is the author of music?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about !

Comment: What is a `JScrollBoard` and a `JScrollPanel`? I've never heard of those components.

Comment: Typing error, it's JScrollPane (both)

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted doesn't show the context of how the frame and panels are created. Some problems: 1) a painting method is for painting only. You would never set the size or layout in the painting method. You set the layout manager when you create the panel and the size of the panel will be determined as you add components to the panel. 2) your `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()` statements don't do anything. Those methods are only invoked on components that have been added to the frame when the frame is visible.